# Expected:identifier error

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, object

I am trying to read an excel table and transform it into a tree structure.
I need to create a dictionary in which the values of each key will be a class containing different variables. The variables inside the "value" for every "key" will be strings and, the last, another dictionary pointing at other entries.

I am trying the following code:

```
'Create new dictionary
Dim dic As Dictionary
Set dic = New Dictionary

'Create variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim rownumber As Integer
rownumber = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To rownumber
    'If Parent node ID is in the collection
    If (ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 3) = col) Or (ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 3) = "") Then
        'If Node ID is in the collection
        If (ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 2) = col) Then

    Else
        'Create a new dictionary
        Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        'Create class inside dictionary
        Dim va As Class
        Set va = New Class
        'Assign values to every variable in the object
        va.Country = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 0)
        va.Node_name = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1)
        va.Active = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 4)
        va.From = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 5)
        va.To = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 6)
        Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set va.dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        'Assign values to the dictionary
        dic(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 2)) = va
Else

End If
```

Could anyone help me, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a custom class and then use that as the object you add. You can't write  New Object by itself as you have discovered. Or use the required object class name. At least I believe that is the case.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr could you please write down how to do what you suggest? I am new to vba and not very familiar with it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read up a bit [on what classes are and how they work.](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx)

---

```
    Dim va As Class
    Set va = New Class
    'Assign values to every variable in the object
    va.Country = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 0)
    va.Node_name = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1)
    va.Active = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 4)
    va.From = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 5)
    va.To = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 6)
```

As you already observed, classes don't (exactly) work this way. The problem here is that the compiler currently has no idea about the class you tell it to use. You need to define it first. Think of classes as a blueprint to create objects. They contain all the information that is needed for the object to be created, to do some work, and finally: to get destroyed.
To create a class, you need to add a *Class Module* to your VBA project. Rename it to `INeedADescriptiveName` (or whatever seems fitting for its purpose, but I'll go with that name for this little demonstration). Then you add to the class' definition until it satisfies your requirements, for example as such:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TDataContainer
    Country As String
    Node_Name As String
    Active As Boolean
    From As Date
    To As Date
End Type

Private Data As TDataContainer

Public Property Get Country() As String
    ' Some conditional code might go here
    Country = Data.Country
End Property

Public Property Let Country(ByVal inpVar As String)
    ' Validation code here
    Data.Country = inpVar
End Property

Public Property Get Active() As Boolean
    ' Some conditional code might go here
    Active = Data.Active
End Property

Public Property Let Active(ByVal inpVar As Boolean)
    ' Validation code here
    Data.Active = inpVar
End Property

' repeat the above pattern for all other fields you want to expose
```

With this information in place, you can then create an instance of that class just like you already tried:

```
Dim va as INeedADescriptiveName
Set va = New INeedADescriptiveName
```

Then the compiler knows that the object `va` has the fields `va.Country`, `va.Active`, ... And you can go ahead and access those fields as you did:

```
    va.Country = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 0)
    va.Active = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 4)
    ' ...
```

---

Of course, only storing data is not what makes a class useful. It would make it a much more useful construct if you also had procedures to go with the data, to transform it in a meaningful way. As such, an easier approach to your problem (as far as I can tell) would be to only use a user-defined type (UDT):

```
' Add this to the header of your standard module, i.e. above all Subs/Functions in that module:
Private Type TDataContainer
    Country As String
    Node_Name As String
    Active As Boolean
    From As Date
    To As Date
End Type
```

The next part goes right where you originally had `Dim va As Class`:

```
Dim va As TDataContainer
' Since va is now a mere data structure (UDT), not an object, no New-ing up is required
'Assign values to every variable in the UDT
va.Country = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 0)
va.Node_name = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1)
va.Active = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 4)
va.From = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 5)
va.To = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schema").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 6)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful! @Inarion

Answer (score 1):

To create a new class you need to add a class module:

1. Right Click in the project explorer (the picture below):

[image: project_explorer]

2. Insert...
3. Class Module

Next, you should rename the class module so it isn't the default Class1:

1. F4 (opens the properties window)
2. Enter the name you want in the field called (Name)

Here's an example of what a class called MyClass could look like:

**MyClass**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'used to transport variable from Let to Get statement
Private tMyProperty As String
Private tMyOtherProperty As Collection

'this allows you to assign something with this property
Public Property Get MyProperty() As String
    MyProperty = tMyProperty
End Property

'this allows you to assign the property as something else
Public Property Let MyProperty(ByVal newMyProperty As String)
    'i prefer to cast all of my inputs to the desired type
    tMyProperty = CStr(newMyProperty)
End Property

Public Property Get MyOtherProperty() As Collection
    'we have to set this property because it's a collection
    Set MyOtherProperty = tMyOtherProperty
End Property

'we can't use the Let keyword here because we're using a collection,
'so instead we use the Set keyword
Public Property Set MyOtherProperty(ByVal newMyOtherProperty As Collection)
    Set tMyOtherProperty = newMyOtherProperty
End Property

'a function you can use from the class
Public Function MyFunction() As Double
    'does a thing
End Function

'a sub you can use from the class
Public Sub MySub()
    'does the thing
End Sub

'a sub you can use only within this class module
Private Sub YouCantSeeMeFromOutside()
    'does this thing
End Sub
```

In your code, you should be able to set a reference to MyClass like so:

```
Dim aThing As MyClass
Set aThing = New MyClass
```

Or like this:

```
Dim TheThing As New MyClass
```

Also, instead of using ActiveSheet, I would suggest setting a reference to the worksheet you're working with like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet name here")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'd argue that if you go to the lengths of implementing Property Set/Get/Let procedures (which you should!), it would be wise to set the class variables (`tMyProperty` and `tMyOtherProperty` in your example) to `Private`. Assuming there may be some validation code in the Set/Let procedures or some kind of access restrictions in the Get procedures, having the class variables publicly accessible would make the Property accessors somewhat obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

With the code provided, it is hard to judge what is going on, but there are a few issues I can spot.

First of all, this code has to fail because you are declaring the variable `dict` twice within the same scope. (You actually never use that dictionary.)

However, I think you are getting the error from the title because you are not closing your `If` blocks. In particular, the compiler does not expect to encounter the second `Else` before the previous else block gets terminated with `End If`.

You actually need none of the two else blocks. You can remove the first `Else` after inverting the condition and the second one is simply superfluous.

Just to be sure, did you actually add a class with the name `Class` and the properties used in the code above? If not, you will have to do that to make it work. If you did, consider renaming it to something more meaningful so that it is easier to read the code.